# how to find a string in the pandas rows where a float should it be?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have datasets consist of hundred thousand rows and hundreds column. All rows should be in float64 (data type) but a few of the rows recognized as object when I imported the file. I know maybe it contains some words in the rows, but I don't know exactly what the words is, it could be "deleted", "com fail" or whatever string that previous user type in. So how to find the string in the rows where a float should be? so I can remove it and convert it into float datatype

Ex:

```
df
date         sensor1 sensor2 sensor3 sensor4
01/01/2020    100     65       66      89
01/02/2020     94    deleted   99     100
01/03/2020     89     77      hello    55
```

the strings maybe easy and can be detected by naked eyes if i have few hundreds row, but if you have million of it, what is the best practice and way to find the string?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For convert non numeric to missing values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processing all columns:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print (df1)
            sensor1  sensor2  sensor3  sensor4
date                                          
01/01/2020      100     65.0     66.0       89
01/02/2020       94      NaN     99.0      100
01/03/2020       89     77.0      NaN       55
```

For find rows with non numeric (if no missing values in original data) test if missing values after converting at least in one column by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df[df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna().any(axis=1)]
print (df2)
            sensor1  sensor2 sensor3  sensor4
date                                         
01/02/2020       94  deleted      99      100
01/03/2020       89       77   hello       55
```